# hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.addURL()

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I recently upgraded by jenkins to the latest version, from jdk8 to jdk11

My setup is

- Docker
- Linux

now this does not even allow me to rollback to the older version as well

```
Also:   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.addURL() is applicable for argument types: (java.net.URL) values: [file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/postgresql-42.2.9.jar]

Possible solutions: dump()

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:48)

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)

        at org.proj.DBConnectionUtils.GetInstanceInfo(DBConnectionUtils.groovy:62)

        at org.proj.DBConnectionUtils$GetInstanceInfo$2.call(Unknown Source)

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)

        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)

        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:105)

        at org.proj.DBConnectionUtils.update_instance_info(DBConnectionUtils.groovy:43)

        at l1_file_generation.call(l1_file_generation.groovy:86)

Also:   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.addURL() is applicable for argument types: (java.net.URL) values: [file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/postgresql-42.2.9.jar]

Possible solutions: dump()

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
```

does anyone have a clue what this is ?

Could not find any documentation to help with this.